# How do I convert my png tiles to mapbox’ pbf files?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am trying to use my self hosted maps in Mapbox GL, but I only get errors or black screens. My JS code is:

```
            var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: {
            "version": 8,
            "sources": {
                "osm": {
                    "type": "vector",
                    "tiles": ["http://ip-to-my-host/tiles/dunkel/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"]
                }
            },
            "layers": [
                {
                    "id": "background",
                    "type": "background",
                    "paint": {
                        "background-color": "#41afa5"
                    }
                }, {
                    "id": "water",
                    "type": "fill",
                    "source": "osm",
                    "source-layer": "water",
                    "filter": ["==", "$type", "Polygon"],
                    "paint": {
                        "fill-color": "#3887be"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    });
```

I copied this code more of less from https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/third-party/
Now I get the js error messages:
[image: error messages]

I am not sure what do do now. What am I doing wrong?

How do I convert my pngs to it? It seems to work with the pbf files I downloaded.